# Wifi getSSID() returns null

Tags: android, wifi

I use getSSID() to get the name of the wifi network as soon as a new connection is made.
But sometimes I get null for that value. This is my code:

Permissions in manifest are correct, because, as I said, most of the times it works.

I use this filter for the broadcast receiver:

```
<action android:name="android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE" />
```

In the broadcast I do this:

```
if("android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE".equals(intent.getAction()))
{  boolean bConected = intent.getBooleanExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_CONNECTED, false);
   if(bConnected == true)
   {  WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) Contexto.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
      String MyName = wifi.getConnectionInfo().getSSID();
      Sometimes MyName is null here even if Wifi is connected correctly
   }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use similar code regularly and I have never received `null` when connected.

Here is my code:

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
String myName = info.getSSID();
```

Therefore, I propose that you should wait 400 to 1000ms or so after receipt of the `CONNECTION_CHANGE` broadcast before requesting the information.

---

Here is one example that will implement the delay:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
        String myName = info.getSSID();
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I used this and I worked well:
   String sWifiId = wifi.getConnectionInfo().getSSID();
   if(sWifiId == null)
   {  for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
      {  try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}; 
         sWifiId = wifi.getConnectionInfo().getSSID();
         if(sWifiId != null)
            break;                  
      }
   }

Answer (score 3):

The Android Developers website states that :

> The SSID may be null if there is no network currently connected.

You're listening to a `CONNECTION_CHANGE` event, what if the state of the connection changed from connected to disconnected ?

Wifi devices gets sometimes disconnected from an access point and they do reconnect silently without you even noticed it was disconnected.

Comment: Bu tit is connected. In fact, I see the wifi icon in the status bar.

Comment: @Halim: I've upvoted your answer for two reasons: a) This is a good idea, perhaps the device is losing connection and then rapidly reconnecting, and b) Congratulations on your Reputation surpassing 1000!!

Comment: Thanks :) Hope it helps, it's the most important !

Comment: Do you have a link to that quote? I didn't find it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html#getSSID()

Answer (score 0):

I've found out the hard way that the supplicant subsystem is only relevant to the WPA security mechanism, and is really not a good choice to use for monitoring general wifi connection status. The verbiage in the documentation would lead you to believe that it's possible, but I had a lot of trouble when trying to use the supplicant actions, including issues similar to the one you describe.

From the [SupplicantState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/SupplicantState.html) enum documenation:

> These enumeration values are used to indicate the current
>   wpa_supplicant state. This is more fine-grained than most users will
>   be interested in. In general, it is better to use NetworkInfo.State.

Using the NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION and looking at the NetworkInfo extra I was able to get expected, stable behavior.